# iOS Passbook Date field not displaying

Tags: ios6, passbook

I'm trying to display an expiry date on a passbook coupon.  This is the first passbook pass I've created.  For some reason, the date isn't showing up on the pass.

Screenshot:
http://screencast.com/t/looDjpqT

JSON Code for Date:

```
    "secondaryFields" : [
      {
        "dateStyle" : "PKDateStyleMedium",
        "isRelative" : true,
        "key" : "expires",
        "label" : "Valid On",
        "timeStyle" : "PKDateStyleNone",
        "value" : "2012-10-12T12:00:00-05:00"
      }
    ],
```

Any idea why this date simply isn't showing up on my pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine. The problem is the built-in OS X passbook viewer does not show the date for some reason. It works on a real device though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be only taking combined date and time in UTC, such as "2012-10-13T06:00Z"

A complete example:

```
{
  "key": "date",
  "label": "Date and Time",
  "dateStyle": "PKDateStyleMedium",
  "timeStyle": "PKDateStyleShort",
  "value": "2012-10-13T06:00Z",
  "isRelative": true
}
```

Comment: I copy/pasted what you had here.  It's not showing up at all on my pass just like my json code.

Comment: Do you try to rerun the app to preview the pass with updated pkpass from XCode? Simply generating the pkpass file will not do.

Comment: I'm using [link]https://github.com/tschoffelen/PHP-PKPass to generate a new pass with new serial numbers each time.  The pass works fine, but never seems to show a date no matter if I use your format or not.

Answer (score 0):

The timeStyle tag doesn't appear correct.  It should be PKTimeStyleShort instead of PKDateStyleShort.

Comment: That is incorrect. As per the documentation, both `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` are supposed to contain values from `Table 4-1` http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/FieldDictionary.html